# Locating Work items which have comments addressed to me?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

In Azure DevOps is possible to @Tag a user in the comments of a work item.  Is it possible to query the items to find the work items which have comments which I am tagged in?

Answer (score 6):

Write a query that does a `Contains Words` on `History`, then use `"@display name"`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Work items** page and select "**Mentioned**" from the dropdown.

URL would look like: https://dev.azure.com/*YOURORG*/*YOURPROJECT*/_workitems/mentioned/

Note that this also picks up mentions in other fields such as description, but I find this to be the easiest way.

[image]

1. "Work items" Page
2. Mentioned" dropdown
3. Note the number of comments. If there are no comments, then clearly you weren't mentioned in a comment.
4. Sort by "Mentioned Date". Latest occurrence by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom query just setting the ID in @RecentMentions like this:

[image]